Why does loop unrolling with reassociation improve performance for multiplication but not integer addition in CPE measurements?
I'm analyzing the effect of loop unrolling and reassociation on performance, measured in Cycles Per Element (CPE), for different operations. Here's the performance data I observed:

Key Observations:

Integer multiplication, FP addition, and FP multiplication show
improved performance with unrolling + reassociation (e.g., from 3.01
to 1.51 CPE for integer multiplication).
Integer addition remains at 1.01 CPE, close to the latency bound of
1.00 CPE, and doesn't show improvement.

Questions:

Why does integer addition not benefit from reassociation, while
other operations like integer multiplication and FP
addition/multiplication do?
Since reassociation theoretically allows running two operations
within the operation's inherent latency (thanks to multiple
functional units), why does this distinction between addition and
multiplication exist? Is it due to specific architectural factors or
something else?

void combine4(vec_ptr v, data_t *dest)
{
    long i;
    long length = vec_length(v);
    data_t *d = get_vec_start(v);
    data_t t = IDENT;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        t = t OP d[i];
    }

    *dest = t;
}

void unroll2a_combine(vec_ptr v, data_t *dest)
{
    long length = vec_length(v);
    long limit = length - 1;
    data_t *d = get_vec_start(v);
    data_t x = IDENT;
    long i;

    /* Combine 2 elements at a time */
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i += 2) {
        x = (x OP d[i]) OP d[i + 1];
    }

    /* Finish any remaining elements */
    for (; i < length; i++) {
        x = x OP d[i];
    }

    *dest = x;
}

void unroll2aa_combine(vec_ptr v, data_t *dest)
{
    long length = vec_length(v);
    long limit = length - 1;
    data_t *d = get_vec_start(v);
    data_t x = IDENT;
    long i;

    /* Combine 2 elements at a time */
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i += 2) {
        x = x OP (d[i] OP d[i + 1]);
    }

    /* Finish any remaining elements */
    for (; i < length; i++) {
        x = x OP d[i];
    }

    *dest = x;
}


I understand the theoretical basis for breaking dependencies and achieving throughput improvements, but I can't explain the lack of progress for integer addition.
Update:

Why does integer addition not benefit from reassociation? It is because Integer addition itself is a low-latency operation. Its execution latency is typically just 1 cycle. So, there is no advantage of functional unit pipelining here.
We still have a dependency as we need the updated value of x from x OP (d{0} OP d{1}) before we compute x OP (d{2} OP d{3}) and hence we cannot use multiple functional units though we can pipeline (i.e. Operations in the next iteration can be started early as there is no dependency between d[{0} OP d{1} and d{1} OP d{2}).


Which compiler, target and compiler settings were used? I'm asking because approximately 100% of all benchmarking questions on SO can be explained by incorrect benchmarking, rather than the actual code.

(a) The loop control itself uses integer instructions; i must be incremented and compared to limit. This must be considered when benchmarking. (b) x = (x OP d[i]) OP d[i + 1]; does not reassociate anything; it performs the same calculation as t = t OP d[i]; performed twice with successive values of i, except there is no intermediate nominal assignment. That assignment may or may not be optimized away; we cannot see because you do not show the generated assembly code or the compiler options used.

Re: your update: did you read my answer?  It covers question (1) of your update. There is still a small benefit to the 2x1a dependency pattern on Haswell, they just didn't benchmark asm like that. For (2), x OP= d[0] OP d[1] still has a dep chain through x, but only every other OP has to update x.  So the latency bottleneck is only half as much of a problem.  Notice how the imul, addsd and mulsd loops all get twice as fast from the 2x1a loop.  Also, next iteration is doing d[2] OP d[3] not d[1] OP d[2]; each element is only processed once.  Note the i += 2 in the unrolled loops.

TL:DR: It does help a bit, but you run into other throughput bottlenecks (from loop overhead) without more unrolling.  The problem here was (almost certainly) the authors not checking that their compiler-generated asm actually matched their source.

This looks like the CS:APP 3e textbook.  In many of their examples (including this one), they use a CPU model that's basically an Intel Haswell.  Haswell has 4/clock integer add throughput with 1 cycle latency, 1/clock imul throughput with 3 cycle latency. 1/clock FP add (3c latency), 2/clock FP mul/fma (5c latency). And 2/clock load throughput.  So all of that matches what they're showing here.
(Of course Haswell also supports 32-byte SIMD vectors, so 8x 32-bit elements per instruction, with the same throughputs as scalar for FP, less for integer.)
Haswell's pipeline is 4 uops (micro-ops) wide at the narrowest point: rename/allocate and moving uops from the front-end into the out-of-order back-end (scheduler and ROB (ReOrder Buffer).  (Intel calls that "issue", and sending uops to execution units is "dispatch".  Most of the rest of the world reverses those two terms; I don't remember which convention CS:APP uses.  I think Intel's terminology aligns better with the English meanings of the words, or maybe I'm just used to that convention since I encountered it first.)
CS:APP 3e compiles their examples with some version of GCC that was recent-ish when the book was written, presumably -O2 or GCC would auto-vectorize with SSE2 if the manual unrolling didn't defeat it, and achieve hopefully at least 4x 32-bit adds per clock.
GCC4.1 through GCC4.8.5 re-associates unroll2aa_combine (2x1a) to two memory-source add instructions into x, to optimize for front-end throughput, giving it the same dependency pattern as unroll2a_combine (2x1).  In fact both functions compile to the same asm.  With all processing of v[i] elements forming one serial chain, it's a 1 CPE latency bottleneck.
The textbook authors very likely used one of those GCC versions; that would perfectly explain the numbers. Those GCC versions do respect the latency of imul (or for whatever other reason don't re-associate it).  And without -ffast-math can't re-associate FP math.
C is not a portable assembly language, despite your textbook using C to show dependency patterns and order of operations.  They didn't check that it compiled to asm with dependency chains that match the C source, and probably assumed that some other bottleneck like loop overhead and/or the front-end was responsible for not doing better than 1 CPE with integer add.
Or they did notice but decided not to go off on that tangent at this point in the textbook. And if so, they still wanted to show the real benchmark number from GCC-generated code, not from hand-modified asm to match the point they were making about latency and instruction-level parallelism, so people could reproduce their results with the GCC version they used on their own Haswell systems.
GCC4.9 and later don't re-associate for OP = + with data_t = int1.  With data_t = unsigned, GCC4.9 turns both loops into the 2x1a pattern, optimizing for latency instead of front-end throughput.  (Which is a good thing in this case since that dep chain is loop-carried and would be a bottleneck.)
Godbolt compiler explorer:
## GCC4.8 -O2  main loop from unroll2aa_combine
.L12:
        addl    (%rdi,%rcx,4), %eax
        addl    4(%rdi,%rcx,4), %eax
        addq    $2, %rcx
        cmpq    %rcx, %r8
        jg      .L12

## GCC4.9 -O2  main loop from unroll2aa_combine
.L12:                                 # do{
        movl    4(%rdi,%rax,4), %r8d     # tmp  = d[i+1]
        addl    (%rdi,%rax,4), %r8d      # tmp += d[i]
        addq    $2, %rax                 # i += 2
        addl    %r8d, %ecx               # x += tmp
        cmpq    %rax, %r9
        jg      .L12                  # }while( i != length );

uiCA predicts the 5-uop loop from GCC4.9 will run at 1.7 cycles per iteration, so 0.85 cycles per element.  From a quick look at the execution trace, I'm not sure exactly where the back-end is losing progress and not keeping up with the 1.33c / iter front-end bottleneck which is very close to 4 uops per cycle.
The extra (fifth) fused-domain uop is a mov load to start the new dep chain for d[i] + d[i+1]. Those are two fresh values from memory being added to each other, so the loads can't both be folded into memory source operands for add.  Unlike with x += d[i]; x += d[i+1]; where x can be the register destination.  This is what tempted GCC4.8 and earlier into making slower asm.  (Or some other heuristic in its cost model.)
In many real-world use-cases, loops are either short enough for out-of-order exec to hide some of the latency bottleneck, or there are cache misses and memory bandwidth bottlenecks (especially on many-core servers where per-core DRAM bandwidth is low).  So GCC4.8's behaviour wasn't usually a disaster.

Another less likely hypothesis
I also wondered if perhaps they'd they'd actually tested on a Sandybridge or Ivybridge under the mistaken assumption that would be the same.  SnB's loop buffer is bad at tiny loops, being unable to deliver uops from multiple iterations in the same cycle, so 2 cycles per iteration front-end bottleneck with loops that are 5 to 8 uops long. (Is performance reduced when executing loops whose uop count is not a multiple of processor width?).  Haswell and later fixed this, apparently by letting multiple iterations of the loop enter the IDQ before "locking them down" to reuse as the loop buffer.  That linked Q&A has graphs of NOP throughput vs. loop size.
But that would be surprising; Sandybridge only has 3 integer ALU ports, which would would be a 1.33 cycle/iteration bottleneck in a loop like this (because of loop overhead) if the front-end wasn't a worse bottleneck.
Or if this was a practice problem from the global edition of CS:APP 3e, the numbers could just be totally fake, made up by incompetent clowns who don't know x86-64 assembly, hired by the publisher to create new problems without the author's permission.  (Only the practice/homework problems are messed up in the global edition.)


Why does integer addition not benefit from reassociation, while other operations like integer multiplication and FP addition/multiplication do?

Another key point is that the other ops all have latency higher than 1, plenty of room to go faster without loop overhead and front-end throughput being a bottleneck.
And that GCC knows latency can be a factor for imul so doesn't serialize that.
Without further unrolling by the compiler, the C loop needs a pointer increment (add) and a compare/branch (cmp/jcc macro-fused into one uop).    A more clever compiler could have indexed relative to the end of the array, counting an index or offset up towards 0, and Haswell can macro-fuse add $imm, reg/jcc.  But then we'd run into the limit of one taken branch per clock cycle.

Footnote 1: GCC not re-associating signed-integer math
Unlike float/double, int and unsigned math are associative, per the as-if rule which means compilers only have to make asm that produces the same observable results (for any path of execution that doesn't encounter undefined behaviour in the C abstract machine, which limits a lot of what counts as "observable").  Observable means "by other code in the program which has well-defined behaviour", not e.g. "single-stepping with a debugger", so temporaries can be optimized away and/or different temporaries invented.  (Like how i is optimized away and GCC just increments a pointer.)
C signed-integer overflow is undefined behaviour (e.g. INT_MAX + 1 or INT_MIN - 1).  This means compilers don't have to care what happens for inputs where that happens.  It's the opposite of meaning that signed-overflow has to happen or be avoided in the asm where it happens or is avoided in the C abstract machine. (See What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior). In asm on 2's complement machines, which includes every ISA that GCC can target, integer add and non-widening multiply just wrap around, and thus are associative even when wrap-around does or doesn't happen depending on the order of operations.
So it's ok to turn INT_MAX - 10 + 5 into asm that does INT_MAX + 5 - 10, even though putting that expression in the C source would be compile-time-visible undefined behaviour and might make the compiler decide this branch of an if is unreachable, or even the whole function and stop generating machine code for it, so if you do actually call the function, execution falls off the bottom.  (Real compilers do that for some kinds of UB, maybe not this.)
GCC (at least 4.9 and later) has some missed-optimization bugs with not re-associating signed-int math when that would be more efficient, e.g. a+b+c+d+e+f or something, where it will do the optimization for unsigned but not int.
GCC has a -fwrapv option that defines the behaviour of signed integer overflow as 2's complement wrap-around.  That does get it to re-associate signed integers; IIRC, something about GCC internals only having one flag to mark an operation as non-associative for different purposes. For example inferring value-range info: y = x + INT_MAX implies that x <= 0, which is a useful thing for a compiler to know when optimizing earlier or later compares.  You can only infer that if x+INT_MAX appeared in the original source, not a temporary invented by re-association optimizations.  But anyway, if marked as non-associative, then it won't re-associate when optimizing either.  And this is why -fwrapv makes a difference.
GCC 4.9 -O3 does auto-vectorize all three loops with paddd (add a vector of 4 elements), but for the 2xa1 loop it uses 2x shufps and 2x paddd to unpack odd/even to add horizontal pairs of elements.  (Compilers often have a hard time auto-vectorizing manually-unrolled loops, especially when the dependency pattern isn't totally simple.  Especially older GCC like that, from about 10 years ago.)  So anyway, the auto-vectorizer isn't totally hamstrung by treating signed integers as non-associative; similar things happen with unsigned so the vectorizer does know that int and unsigned + are associative.
